# How can I SELECT the nth element within SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to select a specific row in a 131,000 valued SQL column.
Unfortunately the SQL server is running the 2008 version and I cannot use `OFFSET` and `FETCH`, so how can I do this in an older version. I have seen many examples online but none with an clear explanation of what is going on within their SQL query.

The column I am interested in contains `XML` data and takes a long time to extract every value, which is why I only want to SELECT the rows I need.

Below is my current query how would I modify this to select a desired row? For example the value held in row 43,235

```
SELECT [xml_data] FROM [SQL_DB].[dbo].[SQL_TABLE]
```

Comment: SQL data has no specific ordering unless you have a key of some sort. How would you recognise this row.

Comment: A table is logically an unordered set of rows so you need some criteria to uniquely identify row 43,235 in a WHERE clause.

Comment: You would have to use a CTE/sub-query and `ROW_NUMBER` to number the rows and then return the row with the specific (row) number in your outer query.

Comment: nth element from the XML or table?   To avoid assumptions, you need to supply sample data and desired results

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
select [xml_data] from (
SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY [AnotherNonXMLColumn]) Id,--here you may use another non xml column to order by
       [xml_data]
  FROM [SQL_DB].[dbo].[SQL_TABLE]) a where a.Id=43235
```